# crypto.load_certificate / Get public key encryption

Tags: python-3.x, pyopenssl

How is it possible from crypto.load_certificate to get the public key encryption ? (for example "RSA (2048 Bits").

I can get the public key easily as below :

```
from OpenSSL import crypto

cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, open("certificate.crt")).read()
pubKey = cert.get_pubkey()
```

But I couldn't find anything in the documentation concerning the encryption. Any ideas?

[image: Certificate]

Comment: In public/private key encryption the PUBLIC key is used for the ENcryption and the PRIVATE key for the DEcryption.In practise you need some more steps to encrypt with your - from certificate "derived" - public key.

Comment: At the beginning of the docs of the _pyOpenSSL_ crypto module is written: _[pyca/cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) is likely a better choice than using this module. It contains a complete set of cryptographic primitives as well as..._ With `.to_cryptography_key()` the key can be converted accordingly and you can apply the functionalites of  _pyca/cryptography_. However, since _pyca/cryptography_ can also load certificates and extract public keys etc., it's in your case probably easier to work with just _pyca/cryptography_ (or a functionally equivalent) instead of _pyOpenSSL_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is really simple :

```
from OpenSSL import crypto

cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, open("certificate.crt")).read()
pubKey = cert.get_pubkey()
keySize = pubKey.bits()
if pubKey.type() == crypto.TYPE_RSA:
    keyType = 'RSA'
elif pubKey.type() == crypto.TYPE_DSA:
    keyType = 'DSA'
print(keyType + "-" + str(keySize))
```